# Old school dungeon with undead toads

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, osr, product-identification, dungeon

I remember reading a dungeon that involved either undead or vampiric toads as the final encounter. Now I can't find it again. Does anyone know what it was?

I know it was from one of the OSR-type blogs, any it was probably written for Labyrinth Lord or Swords & Wizardry. I think it might have been in the One Page Dungeon format.

It was a fairly standard cave-system dungeon crawl, with bandits and so on, but at the far end, there were a pair of vampire toads, who lurked in a dark pool.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You are almost certainly thinking of "[The Fane of St. Toad](http://poleandrope.blogspot.com/2009/04/in-memory-of-dave-arneson.html)" from the Society of Torch, Pole, and Rope; it's a memorial to Dave Arneson and designed to be slotted into the Temple of the Frog.

Answer (score 7):

I know I'm a bit late, but I just spent an afternoon looking for the same thing, so I'm posting it: [The Charmed Grotto, by Dyson Logos](http://rpgcharacters.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/friday-map-the-charmed-grotto-a-full-mini-module/)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Excellent answer.

Comment: Welcome! Can you add anything about this dungeon that'd be useful to the OP?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is most probably not the answer you're looking for, but I've just seen this and remembered your question, so here's a link to an image depicting Giant Vampire Frogs:

http://verydemotivational.memebase.com/2010/12/09/demotivational-posters-suddenly-5/

This specific creature seems to have been made up by a certain Alan Fomorin and it appeared first in Dragon #50, from where it went on, apparently, to be a lesser known Internet meme.